# Four Variable Data Processing Inequality

Tags: information-theory

While Solving problems in "Elements of Information Theory" by Cover and Thomas, I found this problem in the last chapter.

Let $X \to Y \to (Z,W)$ be a Markov chain i.e. $p(x,y,z,w)= p(x)p(y|x)p(z,w|y)$. Then show that
$$I(X;Z) + I(X;W) \leq I(X;Y) + I(W;Z)$$

Note the symmetry in $W$ and $Z$.

**My attempt:**

It follows that $X\to Y \to Z$ and $X \to Y \to W $. Hence by usual data processing inequality, we have
$I(X;Z) \leq I(X;Y)$. In fact $I(X;Z) = I(X;Y) - I(X;Y|Z)$.

Now in one expansion,
$$I(X;W) \leq I(X,Z;W,Y) = I(Z;W) + I(Z;Y|W) + I(X;Y|Z) +I(X;W|Z,Y)$$
The third term in RHS will vanish when we add the two expressions. But I do not have a rationale to eliminate the other two.

The other expansion is:
$$I(X;W) \leq I(X,Z;W) = I(Z;W) + I(X;W|Z)$$

Normally in these kinds of problems, one expands in a clever way and eliminates terms. Kindly help me find the expansion that will work.

**Keywords:** Information theory, Mutual Information, Data Processing inequality, chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out...

$$I(X;W) \leq I(XZ;W)=I(Z;W)+I(X;W|Z)$$
$$= I(Z;W)+I(X;ZW)-I(X;Z) $$
$$ \leq I(Z;W)+I(X;Y)-I(X;Z)$$

where the last inequality follows from Data processing inequality since $X \to Y \to (Z,W)$

I feel there must be a method to this "madness".

**Update:** Turns out there is a method to this madness. Check out Raymond Yeung's book on *Information Theory and Network Coding* to convert the above problem to that of set theoretic and measure theoretic manipulation!!
$\blacksquare$